# Replace backslash with forward slash

Tags: java, regex, file

I have the following path:
`com/teama/merc/test/resTest`
And I want to convert it to this:
`com\teama\merc\test\resTest`

I am trying to append the above path to this path:
`C:\Users\Toby\git\MERCury\MERCury\`
With `str.replace('/', '\\');` But when I append both of the strings together, this is the output:
`C:\Users\Toby\git\MERCury\MERCury\com/teama/merc/test/resTest`

Here is the code in question:

```
    String home = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    path.replace('/', '\\');
    System.out.println(path);

    String folder = home + File.separatorChar + path;
    System.out.println(folder);

    File file = new File(folder);
    if(file.isDirectory())
    {
        System.out.println(file.getPath() + " is a directory");
    }
```

The appended path is not seen as a folder because of the slashes. Any help?

Edit:
Just to clarify, the full path (both strings appended) is infact a folder.

Comment: Unless for some reason you specifically want '\\', you might want to consider using `System.getProperty("file.separator");`. [See File docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar)

Comment: Why? It will work as a filename in Java either way. NB your title is back to front from your question.

Comment: No, it did not work. I have no idea why would say it does work after I have clearly tried to make it work.

Comment: Didn't work *how?* It's worked for me for 17 years.

Comment: The full appeneded path when opened using a File does not print out that it is a folder. I have no idea why, but it doesn't. Trying to convince me you are right isn't helping, I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just saying it isn't working how you are saying it should.

Comment: Telling us it isn't working without evidence isn't helping either. If user.dir + path doesn't register as a directory, presumably it isn't a directory. You haven't produced any counter-evidence. Try 'new File(home, path).isDirectory()'.

Comment: I've already fixed it, but thank you for trying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In java, String's aren't mutable, so when you change them with something like the replace method, you have to reassign the variable to that changed String. So, you would have to change the replace code to this:

```
path = path.replace('/', '\\');
```

Comment: Its embarrassing that I forgot about that...